# How to make two specific images, when a user places one on top of the other, create a third specified image (all of them pre-created images)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, xcode4.4

I would like the user to be able to press and drag one image (ex: image1.png) and place it over another (ex: image2.png). When the user releases, a third image (ex: image3.png) is added to the screen. How could I go about doing that in xcode?

Comment: In Xcode? Did you mean perhaps "by using the Cocoa Touch API"? Xcode is not even related to the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm new to creating apps entirely. I had hoped that there would be some sort of code that recognizes when two objects touch one another, and will perform a specified action based on that.

Comment: @userXXX see, let me clean up your doubts. Xcode is an IDE. It has nothing else to do with programming than providing a text editor and a convenient GUI for its backing compiler. You can as well make iOS apps using Eclipse, using `nano` and `make`, etc. The correct terminology for iOS programming is "using the Cocoa Touch API".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not so easy to do what you want, you have to start to see this [touches tutorial from Apple Developer program](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Touches/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007435)

Answer (score 0):

here is a code sample for the image moving:

```
    -(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
        if (CGRectContainsPoint([image1 frame], location)) {
        images.center = location;

        if (CGRectContainsPoint([image1 frame], [image2 frame]) {
           //place your code when image1 = images2       
           [self.view addSubview:image3];
           }
        }
    }
```

i think something like this could work